# Having trouble writing this update sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query in sql for these 2 tables:

Table1: history(user_id,song_id,lifetime_count,date)
Table2: realtime(user_id,song_id)

Table1 is updated everyday at the end of the day. Lifetime count is the number of times a user has listened to a particular song. 
Table2 creates realtime entries whenever a user listens to a song. So at the end of each day table1 is updated and this count from table2 (grouped by user_id,song_id) is added to the lifetime count of the user for that song.

I'm writing this query but I'm having trouble with the update statement:

```
create VIEW daily_cnt as
select concat(h.user_id, h.song_id) as p_id, h.lifetime_count as history_cnt, r.times as tdy_cnt, h.date from history h LEFT JOIN (select user_id, song_id, count(*) as times from realtime group by user_id, song_id) r ON h.user_id = r.user_id and h.song_id=r.song_id
```

This is the update where I'm having trouble:

```
UPDATE history set date=GETDATE(), lifetime_count=
......
WHERE ...
```

Comment: what is the error can you update the question

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query